# ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE after starting MAMP when enabling xdebug.profiler_aggregate

Tags: php, mamp, xdebug, xdebug-profiler

When I set `xdebug.profiler_aggregate=1` then localhost does not work anymore and gives ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE in Chrome (Safari and Firefox do not work either). Setting back `xdebug.profiler_aggregate=0` everything works fine.

working php.ini file with xdebug.profiler_aggregate disabled:

```
[xdebug]
zend_extension="/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.1.12/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20160303/xdebug.so"
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_host="localhost"
xdebug.remote_handler="dbgp"
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.remote_autostart=1
xdebug.profiler_aggregate=0
xdebug.profiler_enable=1
xdebug.profiler_output_dir="/Applications/MAMP/tmp"

;xdebug.default_enable=1

display_errors = on
display_startup_errors = on
track_errors = on
xmlrpc_errors = on
xdebug.force_display_errors = on
xdebug.show_error_trace = on
```

Anyone an idea how to resolve this?